# Find the slope of the tangent line to the curve defined by $7x^4 - 8xy - 6y^3 = 322$ at the point $(2, -3)$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation, chain-rule

> Find the slope of the tangent line to the curve defined by
>
> $$ 7x^4 - 8xy - 6y^3 = 322$$
> at the pont $(2, -3)$

I'm having a tough time using implicit differentiation and chain rule with all the forms of y in the problem, help is greatly appreciated

Comment: So it appears that you have tried implicit differentiation. What was the form that you got out of it? Is there a specific term that is puzzling to you?

Comment: @MattiP. I can't get a final form out of implicit differentiation because I get lost with all the forms of y involving the chain rule

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{d}{dx} xy = y+x \frac{dy}{dx}$$

If the question does not require you to find the simplest form of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ , then just simply put $(x,y)=(2,-3)$ after taking the first derivative on both side, after that you will find out what does the slope is.

Answer (score 2):

Key takeaway is that for a function $y=y(x)$ then, upon considering

> $z(x) = xy$

One finds $z'(x)$ by first the product rule
$$\frac{d}{dx} a(x) b(x) = a \frac{d b}{dx}+ \frac{d a}{dx}b$$
and via 'implicitly differentiating $y$ where
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(y) = \frac{d}{dy}f(y) \times \frac{dy}{dx}$$ 
Thus, in my example above, one has
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}xy &= \frac{dx}{dx}y+x \frac{dy}{dx} \\
&= y+x \frac{dy}{dx}
\end{align}

Applying this to the second term in your example above yields
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(-8xy) &=\frac{d}{dx}(-8)xy-(8)\frac{d}{dx}(x)y-(8)x\frac{d}{dx}(y) \\
&=-8\frac{d}{dx}(x)y-8x\frac{d}{dx}(y) \\
&= -(8)\frac{dx}{dx}y-8x\frac{dy}{dx} \\
&= -8y-8x\frac{dy}{dx} \\
&= -8y-8xy' \\
\end{align}

Now, clearly, the trickest part of your problem lies in the non-lienar part $y^3$ but the application of the above results, along with the 'power rule' (see below) you are aware of already should give you enough momemtum to go forward.

> Power Rule: For $y=y(x)=x^n, \frac{dy}{dx} = n x ^{n-1}$

**Post comments edit**

It is clear the term in $y^3$ is a stumbling block.

Let me walk you through it, using some of the concepts above.
Set $z(x) = 6y^3 = 6y(x)^3$

Now, 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} 6y^3&= 6\frac{d}{dy} \times \frac{dy}{dx} y^3 \\
&= 6\frac{d}{dy} y^3 \times \frac{dy}{dx} \\
&= 18y'y^2 
\end{align}

Hence

> $$28x^3 - 8y - 8xy'-18y'y^2 = 0$$

Or, alternatively
$$y' = \frac{28 x^3-8y}{8x+18y^2}$$

Now, insert the points $(x, y)=(2, -3)$ and see if this agrees with the answer required.

**Further Edit**

> The Chain rule states
>   For $z = z(y(x))$; $$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Here, your y' is indeterminate, ie, this is the form we include in the above 'graident function'. The other part can be calculated explicitly, viz
$$z=y^2 = y(x)^3 \, \implies  \,\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{d}{dy}(y^3) \frac{dy}{dx} = 3y^2 \frac{dy}{dx} = 3y^2y'$$

Does this help?

Comment: @SamuelJacobi Good start! for the last bit, inore the factor of $6$, it remains. Now, remember $y=y(x)$ so you must have a derivative of $y$ wrt $x$ as per the 'implicit' rule. Now combine this with the 'power rule' and you should end up with $$6 \times \frac{dy}{dx} \times \text{something in y after power rule}$$ question is, can you find out what the 'something' is?

Comment: So far I have 28x^3 - 8y - 8xy' - d/dx(6y^3) = 0 I can't figure out how to apply the chain rule to d/dx(6y^3)

Comment: I got 28x^3 - 8y - 8xy' - 18y^2 - 6y' = 0

Comment: Other than getting y', the only other thing I can think of getting is another 18y^2 using your directions

Comment: @SamuelJacobi So close Samuel! The reamining two terms you have should be all multiplied together, as $$6\frac{d}{dx}y^3 = 6 \times y' \times 3y^2$$

Comment: Using that I get 18y^2y'


28x^3 - 8y -8xy' -18y^2 - 18y^2y' = 0;

y'(-8x - 18y^2) = -28x^3 + 8y + 18y^2;

y' = [-28x^3 +8y +18y^2]  /  -8x - 18y^2   I cannot figure out how to format this sorry

Comment: Using that and inputting the points gave me the wrong slope, not sure where I went wrong

Comment: Just found a tangent line calculator - it doesn't help me understand the problem but I was able to find the slope 124/89

Comment: @SamuelJacobi Please see my edits

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding the chain rule in this instance - if it is even the chain rule. I can understand the chain rule when the problem resembles this (2x+8)^2.  But having to deal with differentiating y is the part I do not grasp

Comment: @SamuelJacobi from the Chain rule (you are right) - please see further edit